# The CSS for header logo in my React app doesn’t seem to affect the logo

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

[image]I am attempting to make a navigation bar. all of it is in place except the logo. The logo is too large and is not fitting no matter what I change in the .headerLogo part in the CSS it doesn't affect the logo. The header part seems to be working but not the .headerLogo .

This is the entire css I have written till now:

```
.header {
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #131921;
    position: sticky;
    top: 10;
    z-index: 100;
}

.headerLogo {
    width: 100px;
    object-fit: contain;
    margin:  0 20px;
    margin-top: 18px;

}
```

this is the referencing of the image in javascrpit

```
import React from 'react';
import './Header.css';
import amazonlogo from  './images/amazonlogo.jpg';

function Header() {
  return (
    <div className = 'header'>
      <img 
        classname = {'headerLogo'}
        src={amazonlogo}
      />
```

this is my code for the app in app.js

```
import Header from './Header'
import './App.css'
import './Header.css'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      { /* header */}
      <Header/>
      { /* home */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Since you're not showing us how you load the CSS in your app anyway, maybe just show the rendered HTML instead of JSX. The problem is either with your CSS being loaded or not, or with the styles themselves. We can't see either of those clearly from what you've shown. Please see [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Comment: Hi @isherwood . Apologies for that, i have added a picture. I appreciate your input . Thanks

Comment: @dan_cant_code: When you examine the resulting markup and CSS in your browser's debugging tools, what do you find?  What is the exact markup in the DOM for that `<div>` and `<img>`?  What style rules are being applied to them?

Comment: try this `className={ 'myclass' }` becareful about the attribute name, it must be  `className` not `classname`

Comment: I have tried changing the css and the jsx for the header. could the problem be in the way I am loading the css in the app

Comment: FWIW you can take screenshots from the computer itself rather than pointing a phone at the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe it will help:

```
 .header {
height: 60px;
width: 80px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
background-color: #131921;
position: sticky;
top: 10;
z-index: 100;
}
.headerLogo {
width: 80px;
height: 60px;
object-fit: contain;
margin:  0 20px;
margin-top: 18px;

}
```